# JQuery datepicker - how to change the start and end dates after initialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am working with someone else's code.  In the initModule function, the code is initializing a start date along with other settings.

```
$('#StartDate').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    defaultStartDate: '-1m'
});
```

I have some radio buttons for **Year**, **Quarter**, and **Month**.  When the user selects a radio button I call a **findDefaultStartDate**() function.  For year, the default should be January of current year.  Similar functionality for Quarter and Month.

> I have the code to capture the correct default start date.  However, I
>   have no idea how to change it since it was set in the initModule()
>   function.

Is there a way to change the defaultStartDate from another function in the JavaScript without changing any of the other settings that were initialized in the initModule() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`setDate`](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) method like this:

```
$( "#StartDate" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
```

> `setDate` - Sets the date for the datepicker. The new date may be a Date object or
>   a string in the current date format (e.g., "01/26/2009"), a number of
>   days from today (e.g., +7) or a string of values and periods ("y" for
>   years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, "d" for days, e.g., "+1m +7d"),
>   or null to clear the selected date

Hope this helps!